# Is this a tempered distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I want to check if

> $$\phi \mapsto \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\mathbb {R} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^2-(1+i\epsilon)^2} dx, \ \phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$$

is a [Tempered Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform). This problem arises in solvin a PDE. Any ideas or hints?

Comment: With the use of the residue theorem one can show that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\mathbb {R} \frac{1}{x^2-(1+i\epsilon)^2} dx = \pi i$. But now I don't know if if we can conclude that also $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\mathbb {R} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^2-(1+i\epsilon)^2} dx$ exists for $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Then we would have well definedness.

Comment: I misread something. $\frac{2(1+i\epsilon)}{x^2-(1+i\epsilon)} = \frac{1}{x+1+i\epsilon}-\frac{1}{x-1-i\epsilon}$. Do you know how to prove that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\varphi(x)}{x+i\epsilon}dx$ is a distribution ? What happens if $\varphi(0) = 0$ ? And if you take $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ even such that $\phi(x)= 1$ for $x \in [-1/2,1/2]$ and look at $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0) \phi(x)}{x+i\epsilon}dx$  ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really see how to prove this

Comment: If $\varphi \in S(\mathbb{R})$ and $\varphi(0) = 0$  then $\frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \in S(\mathbb{R})$ so that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} dx$ converges absolutely

Comment: I'd start by saying that  $\frac{1}{x+i\epsilon} = \frac{d}{dx}\ln(x+i\epsilon)$, then prove that $\ln(x+i\epsilon)$ belongs to $S'$ and that the sequence converges in $S'$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I am skipping some details but I hope that the idea is correct. Write
\begin{align*}
&  \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\phi(x)}{x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}}dx=\int%
_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(1)}{x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}}dx\\
&  +\int_{-3/2}^{-1/2}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(-1)}{x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}
}dx+\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrack-3/2,-1/2]\cup\lbrack1/2,3/2]}\frac
{\phi(x)}{x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}}dx\\
&  +\phi(1)\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{1}{x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}}dx+\phi
(-1)\int_{-3/2}^{-1/2}\frac{1}{x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}}dx\\
&  =I+II+III+IV+V.
\end{align*}
By the mean value theorem $|\phi(x)-\phi(1)|\leq\Vert\phi^{\prime}%
\Vert_{\infty}|x-1|$ and so
\begin{align*}
|I|  & \leq\Vert\phi^{\prime}\Vert_{\infty}\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac
{|x-1|}{|x-1-i\varepsilon|\,|x+1+i\varepsilon|}dx\\
& \leq\Vert\phi^{\prime}\Vert_{\infty}\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{1}{x+1}dx
\end{align*}
since $|x-1-i\varepsilon|=\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}+\varepsilon^{2}}\geq|x-1|$. The term
$II$ can be treated similarly.
\begin{align*}
|III|  & \leq\Vert\phi\Vert_{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrack
-3/2,-1/2]\cup\lbrack1/2,3/2]}\frac{1}{|x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}|}dx\\
& \leq\Vert\phi\Vert_{\infty}\int_{3/2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}-5/4}
dx+\Vert\phi\Vert_{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{-3/2}\frac{1}{x^{2}-5/4}dx+\Vert
\phi\Vert_{\infty}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{1}{3/4-x^{2}}dx
\end{align*}
where $|x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}|=|x^{2}-1-\varepsilon^{2}+2i\varepsilon
|\geq|x^{2}-1-\varepsilon^{2}|$. Since $$\frac{2(1+i\varepsilon)}
{x^{2}-(1+i\varepsilon)^{2}}=\frac{1}{x+1+i\varepsilon}-\frac{1}
{x-(1+i\varepsilon)}$$ and

\begin{align*}
\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\frac{1}{x-1-i\varepsilon}dx  & =\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac
{1}{s-i\varepsilon}ds=Log\left(  \frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon i\right)  -Log\left(
-\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon i\right)  \\
& =\log\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\varepsilon^{2}}+i\arg\left(  \frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon
i\right)  -\log\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\varepsilon^{2}}-i\arg\left(  -\frac{1}
{2}-\varepsilon i\right)  \\
& =i\arg\left(  \frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon i\right)  -i\arg\left(  -\frac{1}
{2}-\varepsilon i\right)  ,
\end{align*}
the terms $IV$ and $V$ can be bound by $c\Vert\phi\Vert_{\infty}$. In
conclusion $|T(\phi)|\leq c(\Vert\phi\Vert_{\infty}+\Vert\phi^{\prime}
\Vert_{\infty})$ and so $T$ is a tempered distribution.

Comment: Well done. Is it possible to show with this technique that also $\phi \mapsto \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\mathbb {R^n} \frac{\phi(x)}{|x|^2-(1+i\epsilon)^2} dx, \ \phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})$ is a tempered distribution, e.g. for n=3?

Comment: The problem is that in more than one dimension the set where the denominator is singular $|x|=1$ is a sphere and so it is not clear what to subtract. Maybe using spherical coordinates and adding and subtracting the integral of $\phi$ over the sphere. I am not sure

Comment: In a book I found the following approach for a similar problem: They first show that $\frac{1}{x+i0}$ is a distribution. Then they define $H(x)=|x|^2-a^2$. Now the say that $grad(H(x))=-2x \neq 0$ for $H(x)=0$. Hence $\frac{1}{|x|^2-a^2+i0}$ is a tempered distribution. I don't really see where the $grad$ comes from ...

Comment: which book? Anyway my solution is based on standard tricks for singular integrals (Hilbert transform, second derivatives of Green functions, and so on) and those tricks work in any dimension.

Comment: I found it in the book of Egorov and Shubin, Partial Differential Equations 2, p. 171. Further the same statement can be found here http://www.oulu.fi/sites/default/files/content/files/fourier.pdf on page 79